# Implement Integrated Security SSPI in Codeigniter for MS SQL database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to access ms sql database with integrated security where username and password verification against windows logged in user. Codeigniter application is running on xampp server.

I have commented the username and password in `/application/config/database.php` as shown below

```
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'HOSTNAME',
    //'username' => 'USERNAME',
    //'password' => 'PASSWD',
    'database' => 'MY_DATABASE',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I have added `mssql.secure_connection=On` inside file `php.ini` and restarted server but its not working.

Could someone help here please.

Comment: Xampp on Windows or xampp on Linux? Not working how? Is there an error message?

Comment: Xampp on Windows for dev and iis on windows for prod. When try to access URL in web browser it gives `A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.`

Comment: OK. Please edit the question to include that info and your full connection settings.

Comment: P.s. if you're using IIS for prod then I strongly suggest using a similar environment for dev, then you'll get less unexpected deployment and environment problems when you move to live. Apache and IIS work very differently in many respects. Also xampp installs other stuff such as mysql which it seems you don't really need.

Comment: Yeah right. We have initated to have the same env.

Comment: @ADyson Do you have any suggestions to integrate sspi into codeigniter running on IIS server on Microsoft SQL Server using library sqlsrv

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16